# Display Message when Registration hits 0

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

**Current Background:**
I have a ASP.NET VB form connected to a database. In the database, there is a field called TourCount. This count decrimates by 1 everytime a user submits a form.

**Goal:**
When the TourCount reaches 0, all registrations must close. However, at the moment, TourCount continues to decrimate into negative numbers. When TourCount reaches 0, I would like a message to appear above the form saying "Registration Closed".

**Current Attempt:**
I have tried a few things, but I'm not sure where it's going. I don't receive a config error message, but it's never functioning correctly either. I'm not sure where or what type of script I should be using. My logic says, when TourCount is less than or equal to zero, display a text string via the id called "Message".

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSrcTourCount" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:recruitmentConnectionString %>" SelectCommand = "SELECT [TourCount] FROM [tourdates] WHERE [TourType] = @TourType AND [TourDatesAvailable] = @TourDates" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tourdates] SET [TourCount] = ([TourCount] - 1) WHERE [TourType] = @TourType AND [TourDatesAvailable] = @TourDates">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="TourType" DefaultValue="JobFair"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="TourDates" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:parameter Name="TourType" DefaultValue="JobFair"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:parameter Name="TourDates" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            If (TourCount <= 0) {
                document.getElementById("Message").style.display = "inline";
                return true;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("Message").style.display = "none";
                return false;
            }
        </script>

In the HTML: <span id="Message">-Closed-</span>
```

If anyone could provide me with some insight about how to proceed, I would truly appreciate your help. Thank you so much for your time in reading.

Comment: Another idea just came to mind. Perhaps I don't display a message via an ID. But instead, I redirect them to another page called closed.aspx after submit. Is this the same algorythm though? May be the same concept...

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering, why are you using javascript for this?

If I was you I'd simply get the TourCount on PageLoad
Navigate to your closed.asmx if TourCount = 0
else when they hit the Submit button
get the TourCount again (it could've changed in the meantime)
If still > 0 do the registration and reduce TourCount
If 0 navigate to the 'too slow slowpoke' page.

The only thing I'd use javascript for is dynamically refreshing TourCount every x seconds and automatically navigating to closed.asmx when it hits 0.

Comment: Thank you for  your help. I'll have to do a little research into that because I'm new to ASP and don't understand all the concepts. I am not familiar with the PageLoad Navigate.

Comment: I'm likely way off, but is this a more accurate direction:

<script runat="server" type="text/vb">
 Protected Sub btnInsert_Click(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 

 Try
  'Forward to Closed Page
  If (TourCount = 0) {
                Response.Redirect(closed.aspx?t=jobfair", False)
 End Try

</script>

Comment: Eh, I'm new to Stack Overflow too..that code looks terrible. Can you only add comments on here with text, no detailed functionality as I could in writing my question? 

Sorry about the ugliness in that paste.

Comment: Yeah, comments are text only. No line breaks even.

Comment: I suppose in summary, if I can add a record to a database, how do I do the opposite and remove the record from the database (ex: cancellation build)? If anyone has any resources I can study, I would appreciate it. Any good books, online articles, or video that highlights concepts like this?